# PostFix get EMails with php and write it into HTML

Tags: email, php, postfix, webserver, html

I Have a PostFix Server where i installed apache2 and php7.2.

Now i am creating a WebPage where i want to display all my received EMails.

What code do i Need to view the EMails?

I tried `echo "type 1" | mail` and this work, BUT after I executed the command, it deletet the mail.

How can i view my EMails without getting deletet and additionally writing it into an HTML Document?

Comment: I think your question is not answerable with the given information. It is generalized, please focus more on your specific problem. Maybe splitting the task in multiple smaller chunks would help.

Comment: Well i changed the text, but still dont know if its understandable